# How to return a vector of vectors from a function?

Tags: c++, function, vector

When I try to return a **vector of vectors** `'arr'` from the  `add()` like this

```
void add(int cols, int rows){
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> arr;
    //do something
    return arr;
}
int main(){
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec;
    vec=add(4,4);   
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler gives the following error message:

```
main.cpp:20:12: error: return-statement with a value, in function returning ‘void’ [-fpermissive]
   20 |     return arr;
      |            ^~~
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:26:16: error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::vector >’ and ‘void’)
   26 |     vec=add(4,4);
      |                ^
```

Comment: Change the return type of the function to `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`.

Comment: You declared `add` to return `void` (i.e. nothing). This is why you get a compiler error when you try to return something. Change it like @AnoopRana mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

The return type for function add is void, thus you cannot return any value, in order to return a value you will have make the return type the type of the value, thus the return type will have to be std::vectorstd::vector<int> for you to be able to return the value.

Answer (score 0):

The **problem** is that the return type of your function(as specified while defining the function) is `void` but you're returning `arr` which is of type `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`.

To **solve** this just change the return type of the function to `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` as shown below:

```
//vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv------------------------>return type changed from void
  std::vector<std::vector<int>> add(int cols, int rows){
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> arr;
    //do something
    return arr;
}
```